# Videos in A-frame

Tags: aframe

I have 3 videos to run in an A-frame scene. The code for the video and j/s works for one. I am wondering what I need to change in the JavaScript for video 2 and 3
Code for video

I tried playing with the js but it will work for one but not each video individually

Any and all help appreciated

This is the html a-frame framework

```
<a-entity>
          <a-video id="berlin" src="video/berlin.mp4" position="4.0 1.6 4.757" rotation="0 180 0" width="2" height="1.125">
      </a-video>
      <!-- TV background -->
      <a-plane id="videoControls" position="4.0 0.854 4.767" scale="2 0.386 1.714" rotation="0 -180 0" opacity="1"
        src="images/tv_background.jpg">
        <!-- Play button -->
        <a-plane id="vidplaybox1" src="images/btnPlay.png" scale="0.122 0.678 0.122" position="-0.350 0 .01"
          shader="flat" transparent="true" videoplayer></a-plane>
        <!-- Stop button -->
        <a-plane id="vidpausebox1" src="images/btnPause.png" scale="0.122 0.678 0.122" position="0.350 0 .01"
          shader="flat" transparent="true" videopauser></a-plane>
      </a-plane>
    </a-entity>

    <a-entity>
      <a-video id="shanghai" src="video/shanghai.mp4" autoplay loop="false" position="0 1.6 4.757" rotation="0 180 0"
        width="2" height="1.125"></a-video>
      <!-- TV background -->
      <a-plane id="videoControls" position="0 0.854 4.767" scale="2.0 0.386 1.714" rotation="0 -180 0" opacity="1"
        src="images/tv_background.jpg">
        <!-- Play button -->
        <a-plane id="vidplaybox2" src="images/btnPlay.png" scale="0.122 0.678 0.122" position="-0.350 0 .01"
          shader="flat" transparent="true" videoplayer></a-plane>
        <!-- Stop button -->
        <a-plane id="vidpausebox2" src="images/btnPause.png" scale="0.122 0.678 0.122" position="0.350 0 .01"
          shader="flat" transparent="true" videopauser></a-plane>
      </a-plane>
    </a-entity>


  AFRAME.registerComponent('videoplayer', {
    init: function() {
     let videosource = document.querySelector('#berlin');
     let videoplay = () => {
       videosource.play();
     }
     this.el.addEventListener('click', videoplay);
   }
 });

AFRAME.registerComponent('videopauser', {
  init: function() {
    let videosource = document.querySelector('#berlin');
    let videopause = () => {
      videosource.pause();
    }

    this.el.addEventListener('click', videopause);
  }
});

AFRAME.registerComponent('videoplayer', {
  init: function() {
    let videosource = document.querySelector('#shanghai');
    let videoplay = () => {
      videosource.play();
    }
    this.el.addEventListener('click', videoplay);
  }
});
AFRAME.registerComponent('videopauser', {
  init: function() {
    let videosource = document.querySelector('#shanghai');
    let videopause = () => {
      videosource.pause();
    }

    this.el.addEventListener('click', videopause);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser policies require user gesture to initiate video playback. User gesture must happen on a 2D DOM element like a `<button>`, `<div>`.. In-3D scene, A-Frame elements don't apply.

You might want to check this from the A-Frame examples:

https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/360-video/

Code available on github:

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/boilerplate/360-video/index.html

You can start video playback of all your vides on 2D user gesture and pause immediately. Then you can resume using A-Frame events.

Comment: So it will play a video and pause a video - but when I add a second video the pause will pause one but not the other and will play both when play is selected. I am looking to find the javascript code so that when pause/play selected it will stop one video but not the other.